# Can't quote array - rails sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to create a sql query dynamically with the following syntax:

```
Company.joins(:founder_persons)
       .where("people.first_name like people[:first_name]", {people: {first_name: 'm%'}})
```

But running this on the rails console gives me `TypeError: can't quote Array`. Im guessing this is not how we use the where string? What's the right way to fix this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind any value and then assign it, this way they should coincide in numbers, like:

```
Model.joins(:join_table)
     .where('models.first_attribute LIKE ? AND models.second_attribute LIKE ?', value_for_first_attr, value_for_second_attr)
```

If using an array you should access each index you want to compare, or you can precede a splat `*`, and specify just one value, like:

```
Model.joins(:join_table)
     .where('models.first_attribute LIKE ? AND models.second_attribute LIKE ?', *array_of_values)
```

Note although this way you're passing the "whole" array it should also coincide in size or numbers, otherwise it'd raise an `ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid` error depending if there are more or less elements than needed.

Comment: ooooo yaas, let me try xD

Comment: I'd like to know if is what you meant, because of `'m%'` I'm not sure.

Comment: oh yes, there is a problem with this, actually the query is being made dynamically so the where string could be `'this like ? AND this like ? AND this like ?` so could I pass an array of values instead of comma separated values after the string like `.where(...string... , [people[:first_name], people[:last_name]...])`

Comment: Yes, you can bind the values the same way if they're more than one, note you don't need to use an array, just pass them separated by comma, just they must coincide.

Comment: that's the problem, i can't pass them separated by commas. I have an array of all the values. So for example I have this string: `this like ? AND that like ?'` I have an array of 2 values for the 2 `?` named `val_arr`. So how would I `.where('this like ? AND that like ?', comma_separated_each_element_of_val_arr)` ?

Comment: Nvm, i searched up if I pass an array to .where like `.where(arr)` the first element of the array will be the template and the rest will be the values so i appened the where string to the val_arr and now it works! Edit your answer to this, ill accept it!

Comment: How would be the query, also with the LIKE operator? and just to know, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is a good solution! However, remember that `=` is faster than `LIKE` statement. So, if you know names will match then  would use `=`

Comment: @SebastiánPalma yes it works with the like operator, and im using rails so on production im using Postgres and on development sqlite

Comment: Updated preceding an splat, I couldn't make it work as you added @Mohammad. Thanks Cyzanfar!.

Answer (score 4):

One reason this error can occur is with a nested array used as SQL value.

Example:

```
Article.where(author: ['Jane', 'Bob'])
```

works, but:

```
Article.where(author: ['Jane', ['Bob']])
```

would give the error. A quick fix would be to run `flatten` on the array.

(Mentioning this since this page comes up when searching for the confusing error "Can't quote array".)

Comment: That was exactly it. You the man.